# Does an Indian citizen need a transit visa in Melbourne?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, australia, melbourne, mel

I am from  India, now in New Zealand. I have booked a ticket in Qantas Airways:

Auckland - Melbourne Terminal 2- Melbourne Terminal 2 - New Delhi, New Delhi to Ahmadabad.

I will be staying in Melbourne for 2 Hours 35 Minutes , do I require a transit visa?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you will need a transit visa.  From [Travellers eligible to transit without a visa (TWOV)](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/travellers-eligible-to-transit-without-visa), among the other things you need to be from one of the eligible countries:

> a citizen of Andorra, Argentina, Austria, Belgium, Brunei, Bulgaria,
>   Canada, Chile, Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia,
>   Federated States of Micronesia, Fiji, Finland, France, Germany,
>   Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Indonesia, Ireland, Italy, Japan, Kiribati,
>   Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malaysia, Malta,
>   Marshall Islands, Mexico, Monaco, Nauru, Netherlands, New Zealand,
>   Norway, Oman, Palau, Papua New Guinea, Philippines, Poland, Portugal,
>   Qatar, Romania, Samoa, San Marino, Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia,
>   Solomon Islands, South Africa, South Korea, Spain, Sweden,
>   Switzerland, Thailand, Tonga, Tuvalu, United Arab Emirates, United
>   Kingdom (including its colonies), United States of America, Uruguay,
>   Vanuatu and Vatican

But it also says

> [Or] an Indian official passport holder

I assume that the latter clause is for government officials .. but that is *my* assumption.

You should the try to apply for a transit visa at [(Subclass 771) Transit visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771)

Comment: Yes, that's what "official passport" means.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was trying to parse the idea of what was "not" an official passport.  Because aren't all genuine passports "official"?  I need more sleep :D  Also the OP may have such a passport.